# Not printing in C++

Tags: c++

This is very simple program i learnt in my first class of C++ today but i thing i forgot something i am unable to think whats wrong. Please help me understand what i am missing here in code?

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
std::cout << "Welcome ..." << cout::endl;

if (argc > 1) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `cout::endl` should be `std::endl`. (Or `'\n'`, unless you specifically want to flush output at that point.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your cout line is wrong. Use this:

```
std::cout << "Welcome ..." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `std::endl` instead of `cout::endl`. Look at your compiler output. GCC tells me:

```
cout.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
cout.cpp:3:31: error: 'cout' has not been declared
 std::cout << "Welcome ..." << cout::endl;
                               ^
```

Which is useful!

Instead of using `std::endl`, you can always just use `\n`:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    std::cout << "Welcome ...\n";

    if (argc > 1) {
        std::cout << "\nArguments:\n";
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            std::cout << i << ": " << argv[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

`std::endl` flushes the buffer every time it is called, which can be useful but isn't always needed.